# how to plot with TikZ a function that takes a sphere and projects it onto 2D space

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I'd like to take a sphere, then apply a linear transformation from 3D (the space of the sphere) into 2D. I wish to plot the resulting linear transformation. Currently my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
lin1(\x,\y) = 1.8*cos(\x)*sin(\y)+1*sin(\x)*sin(\y)+cos(\y);
lin2(\x,\y) = 0.8*cos(\x)*sin(\y)+1.5*sin(\x)*sin(\y)+.8cos(\y);
}]
\draw[blue] plot[domain=0:360, domain y=0:180] ({lin1(\x,\y)},{lin2(\x,\y)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I get the error that `domain y` does not exist (undefined control sequence). How could I go around this problem? Or is there another (simple) approach to do what I want?

Comment: If I try to compile your code, I get a "missing \documentclass". I have no idea which packages you loaded... So please, help us help you, and post a complete, *compilable* minimum example. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Let me know if something else is needed.

Comment: Can you up a picture that you want to get?

Comment: I am actually not sure what that is going to look like. But I want to plot a function that depends on two parameters. Mathematically, I have three points (coordinates x, y, z of the sphere) in a vector. I multiply a matrix of size ```2x3``` by the ```3x1``` vector with the coordinates. That produces a vector with two elements ```2x1```; in my case, the first element is the x axis and second element is the y axis. I hope that clarifies what I am trying to plot. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plot – as I understand it – maps two values to two other values. How should that look like? Besides: TikZ doesn't support a second domain. ([pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) supports more.)

How should it connect the points? Should it first iterate over `\x` and then `\y` or the otherway around?

I've packed your “double plot” in a foreach loop that iterates over one variable while plotting over the other. This makes very different figures.

I've commented the “one path” plot, I'm only showing the one where I can use different colors for the different iterations.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  smooth,
  declare function={
    lin1(\x,\y) = 1.8*cos(\x)*sin(\y)+1.0*sin(\x)*sin(\y)+    cos(\y);
    lin2(\x,\y) = 0.8*cos(\x)*sin(\y)+1.5*sin(\x)*sin(\y)+0.8*cos(\y);
  }]
% \draw[help lines] (-2.5,-4.1) grid (7.5,2.1);
\draw[help lines] ( 2.5,-4.1) grid (7.5,2.1);
% \draw[blue] (0,0) foreach \valX in {0,15,...,359} {
%   plot[variable=\valY, domain=0:180] ({lin1(\valX,\valY)},{lin2(\valX,\valY)})};
  
% \draw[yshift=+-2cm, blue] (0,0) foreach \valY in {0,10,...,180} {
%   plot[variable=\valX, domain=0:360] ({lin1(\valX,\valY)},{lin2(\valX,\valY)})};

\tikzset{xshift=+5cm}
\foreach \valX[evaluate={\col=\valX/3.6;}] in {0,15,...,359}
  \draw[blue!\col!red] plot[variable=\valY, domain=0:180] ({lin1(\valX,\valY)},{lin2(\valX,\valY)});

\tikzset{yshift=+-2cm}
\foreach \valY[evaluate={\col=\valY/1.8;}] in {0,10,...,180}
  \draw[blue!\col!red] plot[variable=\valX, domain=0:360] ({lin1(\valX,\valY)},{lin2(\valX,\valY)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Yes, I was trying to map two values to two other values. The first two values lie on the surface of the sphere, and then that sphere is linearly transformed. I honestly didn't think through this before. Sorry about that. As far as the figures being so different, I suspect it is because two different paths are used over the original domain (the sphere). You can go from the north pole to the south pole using any geodesic, and when mapped to the plane, they will result in different paths. To sum up, what I was trying to do doesn't make sense, but thanks for taking the time to cook up a solution!